# Target.Address & Target.Address.Row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to use `Target.Address` and `target.Address.row` however I keep get Invlaid qualifier.  I would be grateful if anyone can offer some help please.

Code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo Error1

    If Target.Column = 10 Then

        If Target.Address.Value = "Y" Then

            Target.Address.Row.Interior.Pattern.Color = 255

        End If

    End If

    Y
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

Error1:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue:


End Sub
```

Comment: The key is to listen when VBA is trying to tell you what's wrong. `.Address` gets highlighted when it says "Invalid qualifier". What do you think `Address` does? Have you [looked it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625%28v=office.14%29.aspx)? What do you expect `.Address.Value` to mean?

Comment: the lonely `Y` you have in the above code - does it serve a purpose?

Comment: @whytheq: `Sub Y() : MsgBox "Yay!" : End Sub`

Comment: I see that you have unaccepted my answer. Well, I don't have a problem with that :D However I would like to know that after almost a month what problem did you find with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of these is what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sPass As String

    '~~. This is to prevent the code from crashing when a paste happens in more
    '~~> than 1 cell. Also in Pre Excel versions, replace .CountLarge with .Count
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    sPass = "PASSWORD" '<~~ Your password

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo Error1

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10)) Is Nothing And _
    UCase(Trim(Target.Value)) = "Y" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect sPass

        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255
        Target.EntireRow.Locked = True

        ActiveSheet.Protect sPass
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Error1:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Morning Siddharth - thank you for your comments last night and links to your code - really appreciated.  "Target.Value" in detecting the "Y" no problem.  However I'm getting an "Object required" for the "Target.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern.Color = 255"

Comment: Ok what color do you want in the row interior?

Comment: I have amended the post above. Now Try it. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Any color at all.  I tested multiple codes but no joy with this "object required".  I was using this as a test to see clearly if it was working.  When I have it tested I'm just going to change the color and add ".lock"

Comment: To lock, you have to protect the sheet as well. I have updated the code above. Now test it

Comment: Thank you for all the support this morning.

Answer (score 3):

Small amendment to duDE's answer by using the `EntireRow` property ....

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Column = 10 Then
    If Target.Value = "Y" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255
    End If
 End If

End Sub
```

Please use the Interior's `Color` property rather than `PatternColor` property

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The action (row color) it is still telling me "Object required".  Not sure what I need to ammend here.

Comment: strange as I have tested - I will amend with full signature

Comment: why are you bothering with the labels `Letscontinue:` etc ?

Comment: Lonely "Y" is my error.  It needs to be drop kicked.  "Letscontinue" is for another section - I removed out that section to make my issue clear.  Really appreciate your input (and that of others).  I keep getting the "Object requried" on the color line.

Comment: @whytheq `why are you bothering with the labels Letscontinue: etc ?` Perhaps [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will answer your question

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks - in your post you mentioned `if writing data to cell` - in this post that is not the case

Comment: Yes, you are right but it is a good practice to include that. For example It is good practice to include `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` Else the code will break if you try to paste on large cells. :) BTW + 1 For `.EntireRow.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 0):

Target has not property Target.Address.Row, but has Target.Row. It can be this error reason.